# Can't Sign into Cortana?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I upgraded to Windows 10 about 5 days ago, everything is working but I cant sign into Cortana. I went through the whole process and did everything correctly. But when Cortana tells me to sign in and I click the button nothing happens. When I spam the button I can see a window pop up for a split second but then it disappears, I don't know what to do or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Cortana is available in the following countries/regions: China, France, Germany, Italy, Spain, United Kingdom and United States. Cortana is available in these languages: Chinese (Simplified), English (U.K.), English (U.S.), French, Italian, German and Spanish, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-id/windows-10/why-isnt-cortana-in-my-region-or-language

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you [edit] it to include something like "Cortana  is only supported in a small number of languages: Chinese (Simplified), English (U.K.), English (U.S.), French, Italian, German and Spanish. I fixed it by ......